# Get-aduser issue

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

hope you are doing well

I normally use this script to return the value of extensionattribute1

```
$a = read-host "enter badge"
get-aduser -Filter {extensionattribute1 -eq $a } -Properties * -server "Server" | format-list extensionattribute1,Title,AccountExpirationDate,DistinguishedName,SamAccountName,enabled,Description,Orginizations,extensionattributeies
```

and i get the results. but sometimes i get this strange error

```
get-aduser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:2 char:1
get-aduser -Filter {extensionattribute1 -eq $a } -Properties * -serve ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], NullReferenceException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

normally it will be solved after a restart, but I want to fix it without restarting if possible.

thanks

Comment: I suspect that unless EVERY user record has that attribute set or it doesn;t find the rerquested value, then you will get that error every time it finds a record without it. A reboot is irrelevant.

Comment: all users have the same attribute, we use it for the badge number of the employees.
except for service account extentionattribute1 is left empty.

Comment: Get-aduser takes a string for the filter parameter not a script block. Does it help if you change the {} to ""

Comment: still the same error



get-aduser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:2 char:2
+  get-aduser -Filter "extensionattribute1 -eq $a" -Properties * -serve ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Manag
   ement.Commands.GetADUser